# PHP : Find duplicates based on some key values and perform an operation on the duplcates

Tags: php

I have the following txt file:

```
type1|04/09/2017 04:56:59 pm|postid_1|XYZ commented on a post|userid1[DELIMITER]
type2|05/09/2017 04:56:59 pm|postid_2|abc likes a post|userid2[DELIMITER]
type1|06/09/2017 04:56:59 pm|postid_1|pqr commented on a post|userid3[DELIMITER]
and so on
```

I need the following output :

```
05/09/2017 04:56:59 pm|postid_2|abc likes a post[DELIMITER]
type1|06/09/2017 04:56:59 pm|postid_1|pqr & XYZ commented on a post|userid1|userid2[DELIMITER]
:
```

Any help or suggestion would be highly useful. I would use this file to implement a timeline like feature by reading this file line by line.

Note : The type field indicates the type of the activity user has performed. In case of duplicates, this type should be introduced

Comment: I would store this in a database rather than text files. Do you have that option available? If not you could explode on `[DELIMITER]` iterate on those and explode on `|` then check the 2nd value if it is already present append that line.

Comment: you said *based on some key values and perform an operation on* - elaborate that to describe the issue clearly

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Key here will be "postid" along with some other field may be like post_type(commented in this case). this I haven't mentioned in the question.

Comment: @chris85 : Yeah this is a good idea but will it be good when the file would be large. say 1 GB or so?

Comment: `pqr & XYZ commented on a post` means that values of duplcates should be merged?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes Exactly. This is what I mean by saying "Perform an operation on duplicates"

Comment: @Monty, and `|userid1` field should be ignored?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest : Basically I need to perform an operation on both the records. I have edited by question. please check