# Merge all duplicates in a file in php

Tags: php

I have the following txt file:

```
type1|04/09/2017 04:56:59 pm|postid_1|XYZ commented on a post|userid1[DELIMITER]
type2|05/09/2017 04:56:59 pm|postid_2|abc likes a post|userid2[DELIMITER]
type1|06/09/2017 04:56:59 pm|postid_1|pqr commented on a post|userid3[DELIMITER]
```

I need the following output:

```
type2|05/09/2017 04:56:59 pm|postid_2|abc likes a post|userid2[DELIMITER]
type1|06/09/2017 04:56:59 pm|postid_1|pqr & XYZ commented on a post|userid1|userid2[DELIMITER]
```

Any help or suggestion would be highly useful. I would use this file to implement a timeline like feature by reading this file line by line.

Note: The type field indicates the type of the activity user has performed. In case of duplicates, this type should be introduced

Comment: why `userid2` is missed from `posted_2` record in the output?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Ok edited and corrected. But mate you are really giving attention to minute details :(...and not getting what I am actually trying to do here

Comment: "not getting" ? - so good luck with getting

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Didn't mean that buddy. I said because I tried to explain you in my previous question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485778/php-find-duplicates-based-on-some-key-values-and-perform-an-operation-on-the-d?noredirect=1#comment76009845_44485778

Comment: so it was also unclear in your previous question how `userid` should be treated. That's why you have not any answer

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest In a nutshell, I need to merge the duplicates having same postid & type and In a merged record, I want to play with all the values each duplicates. Thanks for looking into it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP : Find duplicates based on some key values and perform an operation on the duplcates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485778/php-find-duplicates-based-on-some-key-values-and-perform-an-operation-on-the-d)